# How does the compiler makes this conversion implicitly?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

I was watching a video from //build, where Herb Sutter showed the benefit of explicit conversion keyword with a code snippet:

```
template< /* ... */ > class unique_ptr {
public:
    // ...
    explicit operator bool() const { return get() != nullptr; }
```

And he said with that keyword, we can prevent this to compile:

```
use(ptr * 42); // oops, meant *(ptr) * 42
```

I really cannot get it, how does the showcase get compiled? How does compiler make the conversion? To what type?

Comment: ptr is converted to a bool which is an integral type and can be multiplied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's implicitly converting from `unique_ptr` to bool, and then from bool to int to do the multiplication.

(bool to int means true is 1 and false is 0)